# Any way to check the contents of another web page on another domain?

Tags: javascript, iframe, cross-domain

Is there any way to do this with Javascript nowadays? I just don't want to check the website for information manually from time to time. When I use an iframe it refuses to connect without an error message.

I assume this is a security feature but I don't really see how just viewing the websites contents like a regular user would do it is an issue. Especially considering that you could probably just write a non-web-application where you have full control which just forges the entire request to look like a regular user visiting.

Comment: It's not "like a regular user" though, is it? It's like a *specific* user who might have cookies which give them access to specific data (such as their email account on GMail).

Comment: No, the data is public.

Comment: The browser has no way of knowing that

Answer (score 0):

You can use a Node.js tool to automate end-to-end web testing, like [testCafe](https://github.com/DevExpress/testcafe), or other.
I use it in online game, to get daily bonuses.

Comment: I'll look into it. This would then be like the non-web-application that I was mentioning, right?

Comment: I use it with Jenkins integration, it support and others continuous integration, but sometimes enough windows sheduling to start testcafe runner.

Answer (score -1):

I think it's not possible with JS unless the other webpage has API endpoint to get all data, and I assume it hasn't. You may want to check "web scraping". It can be done by Python, but I think some other languages can do that.